# SQLite3::exec error (inserting data into a table)

Tags: php, html, forms, sqlite

I have created an application that takes information from the form and puts the details into a database table called "queue". The tables consists of entities "Position" (Primary Key, Autoincrement), "Name", "Service" and "QueuedAt".
I get this SQLlite::exec error while running my application.

> Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near "jghjhgfjhgf": syntax error in E:\Programy\xampp\htdocs\QueueAppLocal\process.php on line 31
>   near "jghjhgfjhgf": syntax error

This is my process.php file that tries to insert form details into the table

```
<?php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('queue.db');
    }
}
$db = new MyDB();
if(!$db){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
    echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {

    $varFirstName = $_POST['formFirstName'];
    $varLastName = $_POST['formLastName'];
    $varTitle = $_POST['formTitle'];
    $varService = $_POST['formServices'];

    $varFullName = $varTitle . " " . $varFirstName . " " . $varLastName;
}

    $sql =<<<EOF
          INSERT INTO queue (Name,Service,QueuedAt)
          VALUES ($varFullName, $varService, CURRENT_TIME);
EOF;

$ret = $db->exec($sql);
if(!$ret){
  echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
} else {
  echo "Records created successfully\n";
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: _Don't use string operations on queries! They are a security risk!_ Look up how to do "parameterized queries" in your language.

Answer (score -1):

Just realised what the problem is. In $sql values I forgot to put the variable in single quotes like so VALUES ('$varFullName', '$varService', CURRENT_TIME);